# Pixel perfect in blender game engine

Tags: game-engine, blender-internal-render-engine

I am working on a game in BGE and I am trying to figure out how to give my game a pixelated look while not making it blurry. I have found some scrips online but I am not sure to apply it onto my camera.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

go to file, user preferences,

go to the system tab and disable Mipmaps.

[image]

Comment: and when you compile the game in an executable maintains that aspect following your advice?

Comment: This only works in the embedded player. To disable mipmaps in the standalone player as well use bge.render.setMippmapping(0) which is the equivalent of bge.setMipmapping(bge.render.RAS_MIPMAP_NONE).